# How do I find $\lim_{x\to 3} (x-3)\cot(\pi x)$ without using l'hopitals rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

While doing some problems, I got stuck on this limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 3} (x-3)\cot(\pi x)$$
L'hospitals rule wasn't formally introduced in the lecture yet, so I'm not supposed to use it. I honestly don't know how to approach this, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1.$$

Comment: I see these questions a lot nowadays. What do so many intructors nowadays have against using l' hopital's rule? If people aren't allowed to use l'hopital's rule today then why was it ever even taught? And...doesn't $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ rely implicitly on l'hopital's rule anyway? Just curious.

Comment: @Mike Since l'Hopital is an algorithmic way of solving limits, most students prefer to use it at the first attempt. If such attempt fails, students say the limit is too difficult and give up. Encouraging students to solve problems without l'Hopital helps them to find different solutions from the obious one. Personally, in solving limits I use l'Hopital only when it cannot be solved using other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x=t+3$, where $t \to 0$.
$$\lim_{t \to 0} t \cot ( \pi (t+3))$$
But now
$$\cot ( \pi t + 3 \pi) = \cot ( \pi t) = \frac{\cos( \pi t)}{ \sin ( \pi t)} = \frac{ \pi t}{ \sin ( \pi t)} \cdot \frac{\cos( \pi t)}{  \pi t}$$
Hence
$$\lim_{t \to 0} t \cot ( \pi (t+3)) = \lim_{t \to 0} t  \cdot \frac{ \pi t}{ \sin ( \pi t)} \cdot \frac{\cos( \pi t)}{  \pi t} = \frac{1}{\pi}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sin (3\pi -y)=\sin y$.  Hence, $\sin (\pi x)=-\sin (\pi (x-3))$. Now use the fact that $\frac {\sin (\pi (x-3))} {x-3} \to \pi$.